# Randomly selecting a character and 4 subsequent characters from a string

Tags: python, random

Given the following string

```
string = 'SATSUNMONTUEWEDTHUFRI'
```

If I wanted to randomly select a character/s I can accomplish that using `random.choices()` For example, here I'm selecting 5 characters

```
rs = random.choices(string, k = 5)
```

But, what if I wanted to select 5 subsequent characters. One possible result is:

```
[SATSU]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a random *index* between 0 and the 5th-to-last position of the string, then slice the string beginning from that position.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to above explanation:

```
string = 'SATSUNMONTUEWEDTHUFRI'

x = random.randint(0, len(string)-5)
rs = string[x: x+5]
```